# DIV positioning problem in IE6

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6, css

Once again, things work normally EXCEPT in IE6. Please look at http://bronautomotive.com/ to see my frustration... the div right underneath the middle navbar drops down. I wonder if I need an IE6 specific hack in my css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is a width issue.

Try changing the width of the ID=SECTION element to 560px and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that was it. The DIV "SECTION" had a width that was causing it to drop down... but only in IE6 :)

Thanks for pointing out such an obvious mistake on my part!

Comment: Glad my IE6 debugging skills came in handy ;)